# Any opensource library for accessing SFTP & VPN Tunnel - FTP using C#

Tags: c#, open-source, sftp, net-sftp

Hi
I need to access the files available in sftp using SFTP in my project (C#).
Are there any opensource C# libraries for accessing file available on SFTP folder  which can be used in my project?

nrk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may take a look at [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_dotnet).

Comment: +1 although my first thought was "WinSCP is hardly a C# library", the provided link is really usefull

Comment: WinSCP now has a .NET wrapper around its scripting interface: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Answer (score 1):

SharpSSH by Tamir Gal

http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

I have been using this for sometime and found it work OK.